# create a micro service with Auth in nodejs that on pass of {order:"ASC/DESC",applyOn:"columnName"}

Tags: node.js, microservices, streamlit

I have this task and don't really know from where I should start and what I have to do. If somebody can explain I will be happy .

1-create a micro service with Auth in nodejs that on pass of {order:"ASC/DESC",applyOn:"columnName"} will return this live table data(https://au.finance.yahoo.com/) with passed filters

2-create a notebook on google colab that uses streamlit (streamlit.io) , user can upload a csv to your streamlit app select a list of column names and see the data within those columns ,
then deploy your data app using your solution of choice so it is public and accessible,
then share the link of your notebook and public url of your streamlit app,

Answer (score 1):

Usually, exact solutions are not given here, but I can try to give some hints maybe for the first task:

You will create an API which has some sort of authentication and fetch that data from Yahoo source.

It makes sense to make that API real-time since it is stock market data.

You can implement a realtime solution there such as WebSocket.

I don't know which languages you  are familiar but here I will drop a stack for fast implementation

- Nodejs
- express ( web application framework for your API)
- socket.io (realtime-comm)
- passport (auth)

Comment: Thank you for you response. I am familiar with Nodejs, Socket.Io and passport.js
I just wanted to get the some hint from people. Any idea regarding second part of task?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have any experience with google colab , good luck ! :)